# Where does Springseed store data?

Tags: directory, storage

I want to backup my data and I use Springseed to take my notes. Where does it store the notes I write? I checked /opt/springseed but I cant find the data there. I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I cant find that question, mods, if you could direct me there, that would be great.Thanks

Makrand

Answer (score 0):

Springseed uses `~/.config/Springseed/` as its configuration directory. All notes seem to be stored in the `/Notebooks` subfolder, specifically.

Next time you are searching for folders and files belonging to a specific application you can use the `locate` command. I was able to find the directories above with two simple `locate` lookups:

```
locate springseed
locate Springseed
```